# neo4j @auth directive how to "OR" between rules

Tags: neo4j, graphql

It say "Each rule is fallen through until a match is found against the corresponding operation. If no match is found, an error is thrown. You can think of rules as a big OR." in the documentation of [Neo4j GraphQL Library](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/auth/auth-directive/). But in fact it work as "AND". My code looks like this:

```
extend type Document @auth(rules: [{
  where: { owner: { id: "$jwt.sub" }}
}, {
  roles: ["admin"]
}])
```

I can only query using an admin account and comes out results belong to the admin user only. How can I set rules to allow both owner and admin to have access right? I tried to wrap them with a "OR", but still not working.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the lib - Could you please make something reproducible and submit an issue on the Github page ? https://github.com/neo4j/graphql/issues

Comment: Thanks, reported: https://github.com/neo4j/graphql/issues/634